# Convert from P7B to PEM via OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

On Ubuntu, I cannot convert certificate using openssl successfully.

```
vagrant@dev:/vagrant/keys$ openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in a.p7b -out a.cer 
unable to load PKCS7 object <blah blah>:PEM
routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: PKCS7
```

Have you seen this error before?

Comment: Are you sure the file is a p7b?

Comment: Was the file moved between servers or uploaded via FTP? If it is indeed the correct format, it seems as though it may have become corrupted. Try re-transferring the file to the server in binary mode (if using FTP) or re-copy it from the source.

Comment: I say it's a p7b based on the file's suffix. I re-downloaded it via Firefox, but I still got the same OpenSSL error...

Comment: @Kevin What does `file a.p7b` give you?

Comment: @NicYoung - I just get the above error message. No output.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in a.p7b -out a.cer
```

If it doesn't work, brings to a Windows machine and export follow [this](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX124429/) guide.

Comment: Note the the OP had the parameter `-print_certs` in its command. It impacts the output format: with it you get a PEM format (starting with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----), and without it you get a PKCS#7 format (-----BEGIN PKCS7-----)

Comment: This only works if I drop the `-inform der` part. Note also that while exporting a key from Windows Cert Manager, DER and P7B are two distinct options.

Comment: If you can open the p7b with a text editor and see `----- BEGIN PKCS7 -----` then you have a pem formatted p7b. In this case, you dont want to use `-inform der` because that tells openssl to expect a binary file, but this is in text (base64) format. You can read more about the differences between PEM and DER [here](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem).

Comment: This is the accepted answer, but it is *wrong*, as Sylvain B explains. Apparently this changed in newer versions of `openssl`.Shall we edit it?

Answer (score 45):

So to combine the above answers, the command is:
`openssl pkcs7 -in cert.p7b -inform DER -print_certs -out cert.pem`

Verified to be working on Windows, using OpenSSL-Win64

/Thanks Bogdan for spotting the error

Comment: Works on Linux with OpenSSL 3.0.2

Answer (score 10):

I followed [this guide](http://hummy.wikidot.com/verisign-pkcs7-certificates) that instructs you to change the header/footer lines from

```
-----BEGIN PKCS #7 SIGNED DATA-----
[data]
-----END PKCS #7 SIGNED DATA-----
```

to

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[data]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then run the command `openssl pkcs7 -in foo.modified.crt -print_certs -out foo.certs` (where `foo.modified.crt` is the file that you saved the modified version into).  This gave me the same results as running through a Windows certificate export as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, the following should convert a pkcs7 cert to a pem

```
openssl pkcs7 -in certificate_file.p7b -print_certs -out cert.pem
```

Comment: Why do you mean this answer is related to this thread ? Because as you see. It's same as above.

Comment: You did not answer why OP is getting an error.

Answer (score 7):

quick solution in my case (a lot of files with missing header/footer) :

`base64 -d $FILE | openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -print_certs`

Comment: I had a base64 encoded certificate and I knew nothing more about it and the base64 -d command saved me a lot of trouble. This solution should be more readily available in search results. Thank you!

Comment: You just saved a man from suicide

Comment: I was having problem in linux.
base64 -d $FILE  fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Decode base64 encoded string into DER-encoded binary
base64 --decode signature > signature.cer
```

```
# Convert DER-encoded binary to PEM-encoded P7B
openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in signature.cer -out signature.p7b
```

```
# Convert PEM-encoded P7B to PEM-encoded CRT
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in signature.p7b -out signature.crt

# OR: Convert DER-encoded binary to PEM-encoded CRT
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -inform der -in signature.cer -out signature.crt
```

```
# signature.p7b
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
[...]
-----END PKCS7-----
```

```
# signature.crt
subject=[...]
issuer=[...]
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

```
# Read contents in PEM-encoded CRT
keytool -printcert -file signature.crt
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. I was going to verify a p7b file I copied from a Win7 host.

I found out that gnome keyring can import the certificate. From there it's easy to export to DER

Answer (score 0):

openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in  intermediates.p7b -out intermediates.cer

My source file was in text with -----BEGIN PKCS7----- as the header...
This method worked for me while others did not.

Comment: Is this an Answer or a Comment?

Comment: Does this belong here at all? This is exactly what the OP said did not work. Saying it worked for you is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the following error:

```
unable to load PKCS7 object
140368561349952:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: PKCS7
```

make sure the content of the p7b in below format (`-----BEGIN PKCS7-----` and `-----END PKCS7-----` in separate lines).

Before:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----CONTENT-----END PKCS7-----
```

After:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
CONTENT
-----END PKCS7-----
```

### Converting from P7B to PFX format.

```bash
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in domain.p7b -out domain.cer

openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.pfx -in domain.cer -inkey domain.key -passout pass:REAL_PASSWORD
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/522180)